# What GMP stands for in php

Tags: php

Recently I have installed GMP php library to do some mathematical programming. It's just curiosity to know what `GMP` stands for. I have searched to find out it's full form, unfortunately did not get any good result.

Comment: It's on [the title of the docs](http://php.net/gmp) and [in the introduction of the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php), and on the [extension overview page](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php)...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, and the answer is so easily visible in the PHP and GMP documentation that it's of use to exactly no one.

Comment: I'm ok with closing these kind of questions for being off-topic but I have often wondered. Is there a forum (like SO) where you can post a question about WHERE to post a question in one of the many StackExchange forums ? .. I often find myself with a question which i don't know where to post. Whether it is about general software architecture and design, common coding practice, questions about which API to use to fullfill some requirements etc etc .. Is there a forum here on SE where you can ask WHERE to post you question ? .. Just wondering ? :) .

Comment: And where should i have posted the question above ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library

The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP) is a free library for arbitrary-precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating point numbers. There are no practical limits to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on (operand dimension limit is 232-1 bits on 32-bit machines and 237 bits on 64-bit machines).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library